# Flask WTForm error TypeError: html_params() got multiple values for keyword argument 'name'

Tags: python, flask

I am working on a Flask application with a simple login form, with Flask WTF, here is my form :

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
username = StringField('Identifiant Client',validators=[DataRequired()], render_kw={"placeholder": "Veuillez saisir votre identifiant"} ) #to replace those in frontend form.username
password = PasswordField('Mot de Passe Client', validators=[DataRequired()])
submit = SubmitField('Log In')
```

The Flask permission route :

```
perm_bp = Blueprint('perm_bp', __name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='static')


@perm_bp.route('/Pythonlogin_1_0/Pylogin', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():


form = LoginForm()
if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
    
    username = form.username.data
    password = form.password.data.encode('UTF-8')
    # Check if account exists using PgSQL

    .....
return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

My html template

```
<div class="fv-row mb-10">
<label class="form-label fs-6 fw-bolder text-dark">Email</label>
{{ form.username(class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid", type="text", name="usern", autocomplete="off") }}
</div>
```

When I run my application I got the following error message :

TypeError: html_params() got multiple values for keyword argument 'name'

Everything is ok when I remove name="usern"
Any Help ? Thank you

Comment: As far as I know FlaskWTForm already provide a name for your form.

Comment: Exactly, and in my case the name of the fields are username and password, no need to reassign them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name` is a parameter that wtforms automatically sets it to the name of the respective variable.
To change `name` to anything you want, you can add it as an argument to the formfield, as below:

```
username = StringField('Identifiant Client', name="usern", validators=[DataRequired()], render_kw={
    "placeholder": "Veuillez saisir votre identifiant"})
```

Comment: Thanks , indeed cf my comment on the post